# Algorithm for cropping image to specific ratio

Tags: algorithm

I need an algorithm that given an image's width, height and a target ratio will calculate the number of pixels to be shaved from the image's sides to get to that ratio, **that has the smallest change in the image's area**.

How might one implement such an algorithm?

**Edit**

Sorry for the inconsistency in my original question; I have revised my it.

Comment: "calculate the smallest number of pixels to be shaved from the image's sides" is a different goal than "shave_width - shave_height closest to 0".  Which one do you want?

Comment: To elaborate on @mbeckish's comment, say the given example values are width = 500 and height = 270 and ratio = 2. Then shave_width = shave_height = 40 makes shave_width - shave_height == 0. Are  they the desired values?

Comment: (w-sw)/(h-sh) = r, sh = h + sw/r -w/r, differentiate d(sh)/d(sw) = -1/r, diff is 0 at minimum sh. Which isn't any help! Might I suggest an iterative, trial and improvement binomial approach instead? You give a concise mathematical explanation but I struggle to see the application of such an algorithm.

Comment: Continuing @tafa's example - would the answer be shave_width=0, shave_height=20, which satisfies "calculate the smallest number of pixels to be shaved from the image's sides"?

Comment: Maybe you want to minimize the change in area between the original image and final image? Min((x*y)-((x-sx)*(y-sy))?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Bring the ratio into reduced form, so that gcd(ratio_width, ratio_height) = 1.
2. Calculate floor(width / ratio_width) and floor(height / ratio_height).  Your factor is the minimum of these two.
3. Multiply ratio_width and ratio_height by that factor to obtain the new image dimensions.
4. Shave the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the change in area, you want to find the largest rectangle of the desired aspect ratio that will fit inside the original image bounds.

So, if the original image is too wide, then make the final image's height = original height, and shave off the extra width.

If the original image is too tall, make the final image's width = original width, and shave off the extra height.

**Note:** This assumes that you are not allowed to increase the width or height beyond the original dimensions.  If that is not the case, the algorithm would be:

Constraint 1: x_final * y_final = x_initial * y_initial

Contraint 2: x_final / y_final = r

The solution is:

x_final = sqrt(r*x_initial*y_initial)

y_final = sqrt(x_initial*y_initial/r)

Comment: what if the original is 4x4 and the desired ratio is 3:2? You can't make it 4x2.66666666667

Comment: @harold - Yes.  It depends on the application.  For example, what if the given ratio had 8 digits of precision, and required millions of pixels to get the ratio *exact*?  Would you want a giant image, or an aspect ratio that is close enough?

Comment: well no offense but that makes no sense. Certainly there are aspect ratio's which it is impossible to crop a given image to, for example 4x4 can't be cropped to 1:5. Seeing as it's cropping, the image can never grow. But that wasn't what I was talking about - given a ratio of 3:2 and an image which is 4x4, the result of 4x3 is simply wrong and obviously not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @harold - That's why I said it's application specific.  4x4 is a pretty contrived example.  If the image was 400x400, then 400x267 might certainly be an acceptable result.  If you really are working with 4x4, where a change in a single pixel drastically changes the aspect ratio, then you might want to try something else.

Comment: @harold - Also, in your example, who's to say that 3x2 is more correct than 4x3?  There are two competing goals: keep the area the same, and change to the new aspect ratio.  4x3 would be closer to the original area, further away on aspect ratio.  3x2 would be the right aspect ratio, but further away on area.

Comment: The OP. His question is specifically about reaching the correct aspect ratio at minimum change in area, not minimum change in area alone (which would be a no-op anyway).

Comment: @harold - But what is the "correct" aspect ratio?  Does he really need it to be exact, or just close enough?  That would be a judgment call on a per application basis.

Comment: Sure, it depends, but the OP did not ask for an approximation

Comment: @harold - Here's another example.  Let's say the original image is 400x400, and the desired aspect ratio is 201:170.  By your argument, the final image would have to be 201x170.  By my argument, the final image would be 400x338.  There aren't nearly enough details in the question to be sure what would be best for his particular application.

Comment: Perhaps not, but if he could approximate he could take the original as the approximation and lose no area. That's not even a problem.

Comment: @harold - That doesn't seem like it would give you a very reasonable approximation for the aspect ratio, does it? ;)

Comment: Yea I know, it's the other extreme